# Dynamically selecting log4j2 configuration in Mule

Tags: mule, log4j2

I have gone through Mule [Logging](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.8/logging-in-mule) documentation but not clear on how to dynamically load different logging configuration files for each environments. Basically I want to control log verbosity and sync/async feature across environments so looking for similar feature of dynamically selecting property file based on server environment property variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2 ways you can load the log4j2 file dynamically in your application either from an **`external path`** or from your **`application classpath`**:-

1. setting the log4j2 file path in your application's `mule-deploy.properties` like :-

   log.configFile=E:\common-log4j2.xml
2. Loading the log4j2.xml in your application **programmatically** by reconfiguring the log manager via **Spring** and load our own `log4j2.xml` file from your defined path:-
   ref:- https://dzone.com/articles/getting-own-log4j2-file-for-mule-via-spring

Comment: log.configFile is to specify custom log configuration but it can not load dynamically based on environments because env property can not be set within another properties file (mule-deploy.properties). The only way seems is #2 option where env property can be used within spring configuation to load environment specific log4j configuration e.g. log4j2-{env}.xml. Accepting this as correct answer.

Comment: Instead of reconfiguring which kind of missing few log lines, is there a way to initialise with this file? I read log4j orders all the configuration factories it finds but not sure how to overwrite that? Any interesting comments?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried it, but you should be able to set the log4j config file at the command line when launching Mule, using the `log4j.configuration` system property.

For example (in Windows) by adding `-Dlog4j.configuration=c:\some-path\log4j-%MULE-ENV%.xml` if your env variable is called `MULE-ENV`.

Note that there are several places this can be set - directly on the command line if using Mule standalone (in which case I believe you need `-M-Dlog4j.configuration=...`), in the `wrapper.conf` file if using standalone, or in the VM params section of the Arguments tab in Run Configurations when running in Studio.

Comment: This will be at server level while I was looking to control at application level.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a bean in your application which can call the method to set the configuration. You can pass the environment name as an argument to this bean, it'll pick the configuration file associated with that environment. You can call the method using the invoke component and have this flow executed at the startup.
Till the flow is executed, default logging configuration can be used.

Comment: Is there anything in Mule to "have this flow executed at the startup" ?